# Get the current page URL (including pagination)

Tags: permalinks, pagination

Is there a WP function to automatically get the correct URL of the current page?
Meaning if I just opened a single post, the function returns the same as `get_permalink()`, but if I'm on a paginated instance of a page (when paginating through the comments), the function returns the same as `get_pagenum_link(get_query_var('paged'))` would do.

I've searched the codex but didn't find what I was looking for. (But even `get_pagenum_link()` isn't documented there.)

I know about [this function](http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php) already, but I would be glad if there was a "native" WP function that does the job.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In addition to Rajeev Vyas's answer, you don't need to pass any non-empty parameters to `add_query_arg()`. The following has always worked well for me:

```
// relative current URI:
$current_rel_uri = add_query_arg( NULL, NULL );

// absolute current URI (on single site):
$current_uri = home_url( add_query_arg( NULL, NULL ) );
```

The function falls back on `$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]` and applies `urlencode_deep()` to it. See https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.8/wp-includes/functions.php#L673

**Edit:**
As `$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]` represents unfiltered user input, one should always escape the return value of `add_query_arg()` when the context is changed. For example, use `esc_url_raw()` for DB usage or `esc_attr()` or `esc_url()` for HTML.

**Update**

The shown example that should create an absolute URI (containing scheme and host) does not work on multisite with sub-directories as `home_url()` would return the complete URI including a path segment. A better solution for multisite aware code would be this:

```
// absolute URI in multisite aware environment
$parts = parse_url( home_url() );
$current_uri = "{$parts['scheme']}://{$parts['host']}" . add_query_arg( NULL, NULL );
```

WordPress core does not support port, user or password in a multisite site URL so this should be sufficient.

Comment: Frustrating that OP did not select this answer as the Solution, which it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
global $wp;
$current_url = add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) );
```

Not a function, but definately using wordpress code..

http://kovshenin.com/2012/current-url-in-wordpress/

Comment: It works partly, but some things don't work like I want them: Parameters like `year` are added to the query string, even though they haven't been there before, and other parameters, for example the `replytocom` parameter, get lost. Do you know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

For me `<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>` works (on a archive page with pagination).

Comment: Impossible. `the_permalink()` echoes the escaped permalink, it doesn't return anything. The `esc_url()` doesn't get anything, and if it would, it would be an escaped URL.

Comment: You're right, it worked only because of permalink caching I think.

Answer (score 0):

1) `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - It return the URL in to access the page which is executing the script. If you need to type `http://www.example.com/product.php?id=5` to access the page then `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns `/product.php?id=5`.

2) `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` – Returns the root directory of the server which is specified in the configuration file of server. This variable usually returns the path like `/usr/yoursite/www` in Linux and `D:/xamps/xampp/htdocs` in windows.

3) `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` – Returns the host’s name as found in the http header. This variable usually returns the path like `example.com` when the you find `http://example.com` in browser’s address-bar and return `www.example.com` when you see `http://www.example.com` in the address-bar. This is quite useful when you’ve to preserve session while making online payment using PHP since session stored for `http://example.com` is not same as for the `http://www.example.com`.

4) `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` - Returns the user agent’s (browser) detail accessing the web page. We can use `strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],”MSIE”)` to detect Microsoft Internet explorer or you can use `strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],”Firefox”)` to detect firefox browser in PHP.

5) `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` - Returns the file-name of the currently executing script. Let’s suppose that you’re accessing the URL `http://www.example.com/product.php?id=5` then `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns `/product.php` in your script.

6) `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` – Returns the query string if query string is used to access the script currently executing. Query strings are those string which is available after “?” sign.if you use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` in the script executing the following URL `http://www.example.com/index.php?id=5&page=product` then it returns `id=5&page=product` in your script.

7) `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` – Returns the IP address of remote machine accessing the current page. But you can’t relie on `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the real IP address of client’s machine. See this article to know how to get real IP addrees in PHP.

8 ) `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` - Returns the absolute path of the file which is currently executing. It returns path like `var/example.com/www/product.php` in Linux and path like `D:/xampp/xampp/htdocs/test/example.php` in windows.

Comment: Keep in mind that none of those are available in your CLI and therefore useless for cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

`add_query_args( null, null )` **will create an array element with empty key** (`$qs[""] = null`) although it won't affect the result.

- [functions.php in tags/4.6/src/wp-includes – WordPress Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L826)

---

According to [add_query_arg() | Function | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/), 
the 2nd, 3rd parameters are optional and they can be omitted.

`add_query_args( null, null )` can be **more shorter**.

```
$current_url = add_query_args( [] );
```

There is also **the shortest version** although it isn't recommended as the 1st parameter is the required parameter.

```
$current_url = add_query_args();
```

---

In addition, note that both `home_url( add_query_vars( [] ) )` and `home_url( add_query_arg( null, null ) )` **might not return actual URL** when WordPress is installed in a sub-directory.

e.g. `https://example.com/wp/wp/foo` might be returned when WordPress is installed in `https://example.com/wp/`.

---

**Update: 2017/01/23**

My version based on the David's solution to get absolute URL.

```
$parts = parse_url(home_url());
$uri   = $parts['scheme'] . '://' . $parts['host'];

if (array_key_exists('port', $parts)) {
    $uri .= ':' . $parts['port'];
}

$uri .= add_query_arg([]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont now of pagination 
but
You can use this function to get url  within the loop

```
<?php $ID = get_the_ID(); 
echo get_permalink( $ID ); ?>
```

Or else if you dont prefer to use php you can also opt for jquery method here (this will help you to make it work outside the loop)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var vhref = $(location).attr('href');
var vTitle = $(this).attr('title');
$('#spnTitle').html('' + vTitle + '');
$('#spnURL').html('' + vhref + '');
});​
```

or if u prefer to use php function you need to get the id outside the loop

Comment: Sorry, but this is just not what I've asked for... + `the_permalink()` doesn't need the id when it's called inside the loop.

Comment: This answer had very little to do with the original question. It didn't answer it correctly nor did it really give any valuable information concerning the topic.

Answer (score -1):

[wp_guess_url](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_guess_url/) is what you are looking for.

> Guess the URL for the site.
>
> Will remove wp-admin links to retrieve only return URLs not in the wp-admin directory.

Comment: This returns a totally different URL other than the current page when I tried using it.

Answer (score -2):

You can use wordpress function to get current page URL

```
the_permalink()
```

This will return you the curremt page URL link.

Comment: Almost; `the_permalink()` will *print* the URL of the current post. But it won't work for other requests, and won't include variables like pagination. So not really the answer @René Schubert is looking for.