# Get current URL (permalink) without /page/{pagenum}/

Tags: permalinks, pagination, urls

How can I retrieve the current URL (whether homepage, archive, post type archive, category archive, etc) but always **without** the `/page/{pagenum}/` part if it's present? So, if the real URL is:

`example.com/category/uncategorized/`

OR

`example.com/category/uncategorized/page/2/`

then the return value will always be

`example.com/category/uncategorized/`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the current URL through `home_url( $wp->request )`.

Try the example below:

```
global $wp;

// get current url with query string.
$current_url =  home_url( $wp->request ); 

// get the position where '/page.. ' text start.
$pos = strpos($current_url , '/page');

// remove string from the specific postion
$finalurl = substr($current_url,0,$pos);


echo $finalurl;
```

Comment: This worked! Although it was returning nothing if there was no /page/X/ in the URL, so I modified a bit to make it universal. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

Actually the easiest would be to use [`get_pagenum_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pagenum_link/) which will return you the current URL without any `/page/*` paramaters.

---

#### Bonus

You can also simply use it to build "Previous" and "Next" links dynamically using the `'paged'` query variable:

```
// Get the current page number.
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$first_page = '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link() . '" class="page-first"><<</a>';
$prev_page = '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link($paged - 1) . '" class="page-prev"><</a>';
$next_page = '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link($paged + 1) . ' class="page-next">></a>';

// And having a `WP_Query` object you can also build the link for the last page:
$max = $the_query->max_num_pages;
$last_page = '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link($max) . '" class="page-last">>></a>';
```

Comment: This is useful, but it also gives query params in the URL. you have to remove those separately.

Answer (score 10):

Answer by [Govind Kumar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/247733/47359) worked, however, it only returned the URL if /page/{pagenum}/ was present in the URL and returned nothing if not. I  needed a universal solution that will always return the base URL without pagination, so I modified Govind's code a bit and wrapped into a function:

```
function get_nopaging_url() {

    global $wp;

    $current_url =  home_url( $wp->request );
    $position = strpos( $current_url , '/page' );
    $nopaging_url = ( $position ) ? substr( $current_url, 0, $position ) : $current_url;

    return trailingslashit( $nopaging_url );

}

echo get_nopaging_url();
```

Now, it always returns correct URL.

(*This is useful if you need to implement some kind of post filters that add a param to filter posts by, let's say, a meta filed. So, even if a user sets the filter param on page X, the new filtered results will always start from the base URL, not page X and throwing 404 if there's less filtered posts.*)

Comment: Very good. Very close. But '/page' isn't strict enough. For example, http://page-me.com will return a value; a value that's incorrect.

Comment: @ChiefAlchemist good point, didn't even think about the `/page` substring being part of the domain name (if www isn't used, of course). That is, imo, rather an edge-case. However, I'd encourage you to contribute by adding code that will cover this case as well.

Comment: Vorotbov - Will do. Please see below. fwiw, there are plenty of words with the substr 'page' in it. I don't think it's safe to presume it's an edge-case. Best to make it as tight as possible. Less worry over the long run.

Comment: True, but while I do agree with you in general, the question was a specific issue, and it was solved in a most efficient way for the particular case. If my domain does not have this substring, then I just don't need to use any regexes which are slower than simple substr (and which works fine for my case). It's not a public plugin or theme, thus I don't need to cover any and all possible edge cases. However, your addition is appreciated and hope may help some future devs. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

My specifics were very similar to Ihor Vorotnov's, exept that I had more than one parameter. So, starting from his answer, I modified the code to use a regular expression:

```
function get_nopaging_url() {
    $current_url =  $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];

    $pattern = '/page\\/[0-9]+\\//i';
    $nopaging_url = preg_replace($pattern, '', $current_url);

    return  $nopaging_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **remove all possible pagination combinations** then use this snippet:

```
// remove pagination from url
$pattern = '/page(\/)*([0-9\/])*/i';
$url = preg_replace($pattern, '', $GLOBALS['wp']->request);
```

It will take care of

```
/page
/page/
/page/1
/page/1/
...
```

and is case insensitive, works for any pagination page number and also will remove any combination of trailing number/number/number...
(tests here: https://regex101.com/r/9fQaLC/1)

If you want to get the full url with leading http(s) just add

```
$url = home_url($url);
```

In that line you can also add any custom GET parameter like so

```
$url = home_url($url . '?typ=test');
```

Comment: Personally, I'm always trying to avoid regexes if something can be done without them (and still stay simple enough). Also, add_query_arg() should be used for adding GET params instead of string concatenation. But the answer itself is correct and does the job, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCurrentUrlSeo() {
    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url($wp->request);
    $pos = mb_strpos($current_url, '/page');
    $finalurl = $pos ? substr($current_url, 0, $pos) : $current_url;
    return $finalurl.'/';
}
```

Comment: Thanks - at first glance that's the same as Ihor's answer. Can you edit the answer to explain what you've changed and why this is better?

Comment: It's literally the same code, except manually force-appending `/` instead of `trailingslashit()` (which, by the way, will make sure only 1 slash is appened)

Answer (score -1):

While this question was already answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83999/get-the-current-page-url-including-pagination) (not accepted), this snippet should do the trick: `home_url(add_query_arg(NULL, NULL));`.

Comment: I've tried this trick, doesn't work. The output still has /page/2/ appended.

Comment: Oh sorry, I understood you want to get the full URL but failed because it was always returning the URL without `page/{pagenum}`.

Answer (score -1):

```
trait TraitURLStrip {

    /**
     * Strips off paging and query string. Returns a filter-the-results friendly URL
     *
     * @param bool   $str_url
     * @param string $str_page
     *
     * @return bool|string
     */
    protected function urlStrip( $str_url = false , $str_page = 'page' ){

        if ( is_string( $str_url) ) {

            $arr_parse_url = wp_parse_url( $str_url );

            $str_path_no_page = '';
            if ( isset( $arr_parse_url['path'] ) ) {

                // if we're paging then remove that. please!
                $str_path_no_page = preg_replace( "/\/{$str_page}\/[0-9]*\/$/", "/", $arr_parse_url['path'] );

            }

            $str_scheme_host = "{$arr_parse_url['scheme']}://{$arr_parse_url['host']}";

            return $str_scheme_host . $str_path_no_page;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask why do you return false if the $str_url isn't a string? If you accidentally (which should not happen btw) pass anything else, you're destroying the data. I suppose returning unmodified $str_url instead would be better. Also, you have a check for the string, but not making sure it's actually an URL that can be parsed (and if not, the following code will break - wp_parse_url may return false, null, int, string and array). Additionally, I'm not sure whether using it as a trait makes sense, not  everyone is using classes everywhere (hey, it's WordPress, right?).