# Custom query vars filters problem with pagination

Tags: php, wp-query, functions, filters, pagination

I have multiple custom query vars to filter products with the pre_get_posts hook and the add_query_arg function.

All works fine except the pagination, when i navigate to the page number 5 (for example) without filtering and then i select one filter, if the products for that filter doesn't have 5 pages it will show nothing.

What most sites do is to return to first page when selecting a filter, but i don't know exactly how to do it.

I have this for a start, but of course it doesn't worked. I'll be appreciated if someone helps me.

```
if ( in_array(get_query_var('brand'), $wp_query->query_vars) ) {
   get_query_var('paged') = 1;
}
```

How i'm filtering:

```
function custom_query_vars_filter( $custom_vars ) {
  $custom_vars[] = 'marca';
    return $custom_vars;
  }
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars_filter' );

function customize_main_query( $query ) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

if ( is_product_category() ) {
  $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);    

  $marca= get_query_var('marca');

  $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');

  if ( $marca ) {
    $tax_query[] =  array(
      'taxonomy' => 'brands',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $marca
    );
  }

  $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
} 
}
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'customize_main_query' );
```

Category archive page

```
$marca_arg = isset($marca) ? array($marca) : [];

foreach ($marcas_terms as $marca_term) {
   <div class="filtro-item">
      <a href="<?php echo (in_array($marca_term->slug, $marca_arg)) ? 
      esc_url(remove_query_arg('marca')) : esc_url(add_query_arg('marca', 
      "$marca_term->slug")); ?>"><span class="check- 
      filtro"></span><?php echo $marca_term->name; ?></a>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: How are you doing the actual filtering. How do the filter links work?

Comment: With the add_query_arg function and calling the custom var in a tax_query

Comment: Can you add the code to the question.

Comment: Added, with only one filter to not be too long

Comment: Where does `is_product_category` come from? You should be using the provided `$query` object for those checks, stuff like  that always references the main query. Also note that `get_query_var('paged') = 1;` makes no sense, it's the same as `1 = get_value()`, both are meant to appear on the right of the `=`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the pagination parameter in the URL:

```
<a href="<?php echo (in_array($marca_term->slug, $marca_arg)) ? 
  esc_url(remove_query_arg('marca')) : esc_url(add_query_arg('marca', 
  "$marca_term->slug")); ?>">
```

Here we see that the marca term is being added and removed, but the pagination parameter isn't, but that's a part of the URL not a parameter

**Instead, why not use the taxonomy archives and `get_term_link`?** Then redirect if the `marca` parameter is present?

- You could eliminate the `pre_get_posts` changes
- the query var would no longer be necessary
- the pagination issue would disappear
- You can use `taxonomy-brands.php` in your theme
- You already have archives for this at `example.com/brands/*term_name*` just waiting for a custom template

They're already on your site, sitting there unused. Why rebuild something that's already there? If you're not keen on the URL you can change it in your taxonomy registration code via the `rewrite` option

Comment: As i have multiple filters, this will reset the pagination, but also any other filters selected.

Comment: Then use `add_query_arg` to modify the term archive link. Eitherway it sounds like an XY problem, where your question is not your problem but a problem with a solution to your problem

Comment: Was much simpler than i thought, solve it with this [Get current URL (permalink) without /page/{pagenum}/](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247730/get-current-url-permalink-without-page-pagenum)