# Add a class with body_class to a specific url with parameter

Tags: parameter, body-class

i try to add a class to the body for a specific page/url, which has a parameter at the end.
the url looks like this: https://sample-site.com/user/37/?um_action=edit

with my code, the class is also added to the url without parameter. i know why this is happening, but i dont have any other idea to get this to work.

```
function leweb_add_body_class_um_edit_profile( $classes ) {

    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) ) . '/?um_action=edit';
    $profile_url = um_user_profile_url() . '?um_action=edit';

    if ( $profile_url == $current_url ) {

        $classes[] = 'leweb-um-profile-edit';

    }

    return $classes;

}
add_filter( 'body_class','leweb_add_body_class_um_edit_profile' );
```

Comment: i found the answer, its well described here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83999/get-the-current-page-url-including-pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it a bit. `?um_action=edit` is a query string, and its values are available in the `$_GET` superglobal. To check if it exists, and has a specific value, you just need to do this:

```
function leweb_add_body_class_um_edit_profile( $classes ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['um_action'] ) && 'edit' === $_GET['um_action'] ) {
        $classes[] = 'leweb-um-profile-edit';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class','leweb_add_body_class_um_edit_profile' );
```

Comment: perfect, thanks