# How to prevent action in ajax request, when in admin side?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, actions

I have a plugin that hides certain posts in the frontend. For this to be consistent, I need posts to also be hidden in searches and AJAX searches (needs to work with any theme and search).

To make this work with AJAX search, I am using:

```
if ( wp_doing_ajax() ){
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array($this, 'plugin_function_set_visibility') );
}
```

My only problem is, this also hides the posts in the admin dashboard, posts can no longer be edited.

**is_admin()** does not work in this situation, it returns true for any admin-ajax request

Comment: An admin AJAX request doesn't know what kind of page made the request, so you can't rely on `is_admin` etc, those function refer to the current request, not the one that generated the page. Instead of asking how to fix your solution, have you considered asking how to fix your original problem instead? Then using what you did as an example that didn't quite work? E.g. if we knew what was in `plugin_function_set_visibility` it might be possible to tweak it to only apply to the searches that happen on the frontend, or just to those actions that need modifying

Comment: I get what you're saying. I tried going that route initially but didn't have any success. What the function is doing is $q->set('post__in',$allTheIDs); only includes particular posts. These are products that I am trying to remove in WooCommerce. In the public side I'm using woocommerce_product_query filter, but this doesn't work in AJAX for some reason. I've resorted to using pre_get_posts.    Anyway, seems to work for now. Please tell me, when you say "this won't work in browsers that strip the referers", what browsers would that be?

Comment: browsers that have privacy options turned on and privacy extensions, so it could be any of the major browsers, there's also various methods of not sending referrers such as meta tag, `rel` attributes, etc. Also keep in mind that the REST API will expose products too, and the code making AJAX requests to the REST API may not be a website, e.g. the WooCommerce app. This also wouldn't apply to XMLRPC, so any Jetpack or Woo cloud related functionality would be unaffected

Comment: Instead it would be better to check the AJAX actions value and only run if it matches a predefined whitelist, or isn't in a predefined blacklist. You could also look at things another way and restrict based on user role, or logged in vs logged out

Comment: Thanks and you're right, already saw some issues with it. Based on user role is a good idea, I think I'll restrict it for anyone who's not admin or shop manager, that should do it

Answer (score 1):

After testing a lot of things, I found this function, which works:

```
function is_admin_request() {
                        /**
                         * Get current URL.
                         *
                         * @link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126534
                         */
                        $current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( null, null ) );

                        /**
                         * Get admin URL and referrer.
                         *
                         * @link https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1076
                         */
                        $admin_url = strtolower( admin_url() );
                        $referrer  = strtolower( wp_get_referer() );

                        /**
                         * Check if this is a admin request. If true, it
                         * could also be a AJAX request from the frontend.
                         */
                        if ( 0 === strpos( $current_url, $admin_url ) ) {
                            /**
                             * Check if the user comes from a admin page.
                             */
                            if ( 0 === strpos( $referrer, $admin_url ) ) {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                /**
                                 * Check for AJAX requests.
                                 *
                                 * @link https://gist.github.com/zitrusblau/58124d4b2c56d06b070573a99f33b9ed#file-lazy-load-responsive-images-php-L193
                                 */
                                if ( function_exists( 'wp_doing_ajax' ) ) {
                                    return ! wp_doing_ajax();
                                } else {
                                    return ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX );
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This won't work in browsers that strip the referrer from requests